# Writing specs for grammar in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I have written my own grammar in atom. I would like to write some specs for the same, but I am unable to understand how exactly to write one. I read the Jasmine documentation, but still not very clear. Can someone please explain how to write specs for testing out grammar in atom. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Grammars are availabe available under `atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName("source.yourlanguage")`
- The grammar object it returns has methods you can feed code snippets (e.g. `tokenizeLine`, `tokenizeLines`).
- These methods return arrays of tokens.
- Testing is just verifying if these methods return what you expect.

E.g. (CoffeeScript alert):

```
grammar = atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName("source.yourlanguage")
{tokens} = grammar.tokenizeLine("# this is a comment line of some sort")

expect(tokens[0].value).toEqual "#"
expect(tokens[0].scopes).toEqual [
    "source.yourlanguage",
    "comment.line.number-sign.yourlanguage",
    "punctuation.definition.comment.yourlanguage"
]
```

Happy testing!

- Example specs

  - [spec for MscGen (a simple language)](https://github.com/mscgenjs/atom-language-mscgen/blob/master/spec/mscgen-grammar-spec.coffee)
  - [spec for Haskell (more complex)](https://github.com/atom-haskell/language-haskell/blob/master/spec/language-haskell-spec.coffee)
- The array returned by the `grammar.tokenizeLine` call above looks like this:

  ```
  [
    {
      "value": "#",
      "scopes": [
        "source.yourlanguage",
        "comment.line.number-sign.yourlanguage",
        "punctuation.definition.comment.yourlanguage"
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": " this is a comment line of some sort",
      "scopes": [
        "source.yourlanguage",
        "comment.line.number-sign.yourlanguage"
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "",
      "scopes": [
        "source.yourlanguage",
        "comment.line.number-sign.yourlanguage"
      ]
    }
  ]
  ```

(Kept seeing this question pop up in the search results when I was looking for an answer to the same question - so just as well document it here.)